# JdbcTemplate.query() poor Perfromance

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, jdbc, spring-jdbc

I'm using Java Spring Boot with Jersey, Spring JDBC and MariaDB, and got very bad performance. My goal is to query 25 records from a table, and this takes 2.7 - 3 seconds and the MariaDB Server and the application are both running on the same host.

The table has 100 records, and the column I'm filtering on is indexed. With MySQL Workbench, the result shows up instantly.

```java
JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
final String SQL_SELECT_ALL_TEMPLATES = "SELECT uuid, owner, displayname, template, type, created_at, updated_at FROM templates WHERE owner = ? ORDER BY updated_at DESC, created_at DESC LIMIT ? OFFSET ?;";
List<Template> templates = jdbcTemplate.query(SQL_SELECT_ALL_TEMPLATES, new TemplateMapper(), '05e1e15a-5620-4330-b77f-0ac2fff106c5', 25, 0);
```

```java
@Bean
DataSource dataSource() {
    DriverManagerDataSource driverManagerDataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
    driverManagerDataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/mydatabase");
    driverManagerDataSource.setUsername("root");
    driverManagerDataSource.setPassword("");
    driverManagerDataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
    return driverManagerDataSource;
}
```

```xml
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jersey</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>at.favre.lib</groupId>
        <artifactId>bcrypt</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.auth0</groupId>
        <artifactId>java-jwt</artifactId>
        <version>3.11.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>8.0.22</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.6</version>
    </dependency>
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.test-framework</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-test-framework-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.27</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.test-framework.providers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-test-framework-provider-inmemory</artifactId>
        <version>2.32</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: In which place is the query executed? Did you meassure the time directly before and after the 3 lines of code?

Comment: The query is executed with the dao method and yes before and after the code above.